# How to make cell readonly if the second cell is empty

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

The user should not be able to input a qty where the unit is empty in the datagridview.

To make it clear, I want to make the cell readonly = true if unit column is empty.

The colUOM4 is the name of the column that if the cell of this column is empty the olNewQty2 cell will be readonly.

I tried this code but it didn't work

```
 Public Sub UnitEmpty()
    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvCount.RowCount - 1
        If dgvCount.Rows(i).Cells("colUOM4").Value Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("It worked!")
            dgvCount.Rows(i).Cells("colNewQty2").ReadOnly = True
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing happened!")

            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image: this is my datagridview and the name for it is dgvCount]

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not using a loop because that will only set the state when you execute it and not react to any changes.  I'd suggest working at the row and cell level, i.e. set the default state when a row is added and then react when a specific cell changes, e.g.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowsAdded
    For i = e.RowIndex To e.RowIndex + e.RowCount - 1
        'Make the first cell in each new row read-only by default.
        DataGridView1(0, i).ReadOnly = True
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
    'Check whether the change is in the second column.
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
        Dim row = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

        'Make the first cell in the row read-only if and only if the second cell is empty.
        row.Cells(0).ReadOnly = (row.Cells(1).Value Is Nothing)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: it didn't work.. it's still can edit the other column even the second column cells is empty

Comment: I copied that code directly from a test project that worked for me so I suspect that you did something wrong.  I started with an empty grid and entered new rows directly.  Does it work in that case for you?  What exactly did you do when it didn't work?

Comment: Is your grid bound to a `DataTable`?  If so then testing for `Nothing` is pointless as "empty" cells will actually contain `DBNull.Value`.